# Не правильно работает календарь

Tags: javascript

**Задание**: Нужно сделать так, чтобы в поле можно было ввести дату не меньше чем **послезавтрашний день** и не больше чем **на пол года больше**, например если сегодня `15.11.2016`, тогда должно быть не меньше `17.11.2016` *(иначе дата должна становиться `17.11.2016`)* и не больше чем `15.05.2016` *(если больше, нужно чтобы дата становилась `15.05.2016`)*.

**Проблема**: Если ввести дату меньше чем послезавтра, например сегодняшний день (15.11.2016), тогда все работает, дата становится на два дня больше, а вот если дата больше чем +2 дня, тогда не работает.

Код с костылями, не так давно пишу на javascript, буду рад если кто-то исправит.

```js
var myDate = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №1
var todayDate = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №2

myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+2); // к дате №1 добавляем 2 дня
todayDate.setMonth(todayDate.getMonth()+6); // к дате №2 добавляем 6 месяцев

var tomorrow = ("0" + (myDate.getDate())).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + myDate.getFullYear(); // делаем дату №1 вида 31.12.2016

var pieceyear = ("0" + (todayDate.getDate())).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + todayDate.getFullYear(); // делаем дату №2 вида 31.12.2016

$('#datepicker').val(tomorrow); // значение поля становится на 2 дня больше сегодняшнего дня

function datevalidate() {
 if($('#datepicker').val() < tomorrow) { // если дата меньше чем послезавтра
  $('#datepicker').val(tomorrow); // присваиваем дату послезавтра
 } else if ($('#datepicker').val() > pieceyear) { // если дата больше чем + пол года
  $('#datepicker').val(pieceyear); // присваиваем дату на пол года больше
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="datevalidate()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты сравниваешь строки. А строки сравниваются посимвольно и в текущем формате дата послезавтра *больше* чем *через полгода*.

```js
console.log('17.11.2016', '15.05.2017', '17.11.2016' > '15.05.2017')
```

В качестве решения можно поменять формат для сравнения. В формате `yyyy-MM-dd` сравнение дат происходит корректно даже если даты в строке.

```js
console.log('2016.11.17', '2017.05.15', '2016.11.17'> '2017.05.15')
```

Если формат в инпуте принципиален, при проверке можно просто перегруппировать части строки, например с помощью регулярного выражения:

```js
var myDate = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №1
var todayDate = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №2

function dateFormat(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '.' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
}

function outputDate(date) {
  return date.replace(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/, '$3.$2.$1');
}

myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2); // к дате №1 добавляем 2 дня
todayDate.setMonth(todayDate.getMonth() + 6); // к дате №2 добавляем 6 месяцев

var tomorrow = dateFormat(myDate); // делаем дату №1 вида 2016.12.31

var pieceyear = dateFormat(todayDate); // делаем дату №2 вида 2016.12.31

$('#datepicker').val(outputDate(tomorrow)); // значение поля становится на 2 дня больше сегодняшнего дня

function datevalidate() {
  var value = outputDate($('#datepicker').val());
  if (value < tomorrow) { // если дата меньше чем послезавтра
    $('#datepicker').val(outputDate(tomorrow)); // присваиваем дату послезавтра
  } else if (value > pieceyear) { // если дата больше чем + пол года
    $('#datepicker').val(outputDate(pieceyear)); // присваиваем дату на пол года больше
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="datevalidate()">
```

Но лучше работать с датами:

```js
var tomorrow = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №1
var pieceyear = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №2

function dateFormat(date) {
  return ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + date.getFullYear();
}

function parseDate(dateStr) {
  var parts = dateStr.split('.');
  return new Date(+parts[2], -1 + (+parts[1]), +parts[0]);
}

tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2); // к дате №1 добавляем 2 дня
pieceyear.setMonth(pieceyear.getMonth() + 6); // к дате №2 добавляем 6 месяцев

$('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(tomorrow)); // значение поля становится на 2 дня больше сегодняшнего дня

function datevalidate() {
  var value = parseDate($('#datepicker').val());
  if (value < tomorrow) { // если дата меньше чем послезавтра
    $('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(tomorrow)); // присваиваем дату послезавтра
  } else if (value > pieceyear) { // если дата больше чем + пол года
    $('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(pieceyear)); // присваиваем дату на пол года больше
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="datevalidate()">
```

Comment: спасибо большое, воспользовался последним вариантом.

Comment: только еще один баг есть, если ввести в поле например 99, то так и будет. Я думал сделать чтобы проверяло на вид `хх.хх.хххх`, что думаете?

Comment: @Abmin, ну тут уж как хочешь :-) можешь проверять. можешь в дату приводить